# SQL PowerShell Snapin Problems

Tags: sql-server, powershell, pssnapin

I am currently trying to execute the command 
`add-sqlsnappin`

which give me error message

```
SQL Server Provider for Windows PowerShell is not installed.
At C:\deploy\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.1.4\Modules\DeployCommerceDatabase\DeployCommerceDatabase.psm1:215 char:9
+         throw "SQL Server Provider for Windows PowerShell is not inst ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (SQL Server Prov... not installed.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SQL Server Provider for Windows PowerShell is not installed.
```

Which cannot be true since

```
if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name SqlServer) {
>>     Write-Host "Module exists"
>> } else {
>>     Write-Host "Module does not exist"
>> }
Module exists
```

so why can i not add-sqlsnapin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sqlserver` module and SQL Server snap-in aren't the same thing. So, the module existing doesn't mean the snap-in is registered in-order for you to load it. Give the [Running SQL Server PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/cc281962(v=sql.105)#adding-the-sql-server-snap-ins-to-windows-powershell) on MSDN a look. If you want the SqlServer module, try the following:

```
Import-Module sqlserver
```

Comment: Import does not seem to work.. 
And the powershell script paths are incorrect.

Comment: Little more information. What did you do? What did you get? What's your environment setup?